# Meteor coffeescript source maps in production

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, source-maps

Is there a way to get coffee script source maps when deploying to meteor.com or Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy with `--debug` to meteor deploy hosting. I'm not sure about deploying to Heroku since you would be using a bundle (if you use the meteorite buildpack).